# Does there exist a regular graph of degree 4, diameter 3, 32 vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a regular graph of degree 4 having its diameter equal to three and its number of vertices equal to 32? What I know is http://www-ma4.upc.es/~comellas/delta-d/desc_g/desc_g3.html
( the second graph).

Comment: By this address: 

mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticGraph.html 

and a probabilistic program that I wrote in Maple (and with 20 min run, that I know it is very small time), I think there is not such a graph. It is interesting for me if such a graph exist. Also, I think Dear McKay with Naughty software, can help you more than me. Also, it is obvious that, such a graph (if it exist) is not strongly regular.

Comment: Hi Shahrooz! I have two of order 30 and one of order 35. It would be strange if there is none of order 32, but I guess it is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an adjacency list, it's 4-regular, so there should be 4 vertices per line.   I'm sure it will be easier for you to get the graph that for me to figure out the software interface here.

```
14    3    9   24
 5    8   25    3
30   16   21    7
 1    0   29   30
15   28   23   11
28   16   26    1
31   19   10   23
20   27    2   29
15   14    1   22
 0   13   17   28
 6   21   22   25
17   13   18    4
20   24   26   22
 9   11   25   20
 8    0   31   19
21    4    8   24
 5   31   20    2
 9   11   30   27
31   11   26   30
 6   28   14   27
13   16   12    7
10   24    2   15
12   10    8   27
26   29    4    6
12   21    0   15
10   13    1   29
12    5   23   18
19   17    7   22
 5   19    4    9
23    3    7   25
17    2    3   18
16   18    6   14
```

There appear to be many such graphs.

---

(*Added by J.O'Rourke*).
Here is the graph above, but with vertices labeled from $1$ to $32$ rather than $0$ to $31$:

          [image: Special Graph]

Comment: Great. Confirmed.

Comment: The sparse6 string of the graph:  ':_b?@d@fA`_eclHJ_GcGaDhJjeMfKLOaINgIKcE_KNT`ILdKQVfPRUcDHRbFVXaBPQeMOQ'

Comment: By the way, there are no Cayley graphs with these properties.

Comment: Very nice, dear geoffreyexoo, what was your strategy for finding this graph? I found some 4-regular graphs with diameter 4. Also by some papers that BOLLOBAS and his coworkers wrote, I think there are a little number of such graph that you found one of them.    

Comment: The first 10 such graphs that I found were all different (not isomorphic), so I figured there are probably more than 10.
The method is the same one I used to find some of the other
graphs at the web site mentioned in the question.  Roughly, it's
this: pick a vertex, construct a tree of radius three degree four
emanating from that vertex.  Pick another vertex and repeat, using
as many existing edges as possible, etc.  When you get stuck, back
up.  It's 15 year old program and my memory of it is a bit hazy.

Comment: I'm up to 258 examples.  I guess that's a lot?

Comment: Dear geoffreyexoo, thanks for your explanation. For me, the number of examples that you found is sufficient to accept my wrong imagination. But, these number of graphs among all 4-regular graphs with 32 vertices is very small.